# Interface not inferred after type guard

Tags: typescript

Here’s the set up for a couple different kind of node classes, some which have a `children` property, each of which can contain a subset of those classes. In the end, there’s a type alias (`NodeABC`) tying all the the types together.

There’s also an interface that defines the union of all the possible types that could be the `children`.

The final piece is a type guard function (`hasChildren`) to check the object which uses this unified interface.

```
class NodeA {
    children: NodeA[]
}
class NodeB {}
class NodeC {
    children: NodeBC[]
}

type NodeAB = NodeA | NodeB
type NodeBC = NodeB | NodeC
type NodeABC = NodeAB | NodeBC

interface WithChildren {
    children: NodeABC[]
}

const hasChildren = (item: NodeABC): item is WithChildren => {
    return "children" in item
}
```

Now, when I make a list with all node types and try to iterate over it and access the children:

```
const list = [new NodeA(), new NodeB(), new NodeC()] as NodeABC[]
```

list.forEach(item => {
    if (!hasChildren(item)) {
        return
    }
    // Type error here (no compatible call signatures)
    item.children.forEach((child: NodeABC) => {}) 
})

This will *not* work. It correctly sees that the `item` can not be `NodeB`, but it `children` will not have the interface of the type guard, but rather the union of the `NodeA`’s and `NodeC`’s `children` property. I can add a cast of course, but that would need to happen all the time.

The workaround I found now is this (without casts):

```
const getChildren = (item: NodeABC): NodeABC[] => {
    return hasChildren(item) ? item.children : []
}

list.forEach(item => {
    getChildren(item).forEach(child => {})
})
```

Which is fine, but I’d love to understand why the first solution does not work? The type guard is obviously not “strong” enough to convince the rest of the type system, which somewhat makes sense, but in this case the alias I want should be equal to the inferred type. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried to let the compiler infer the type for _list_ to see the effect that it would have in the original code?

Comment: Yes, that works, but only because then it infers the type of the list as `NodeB[]`. I can trigger some other typings (and errors) by adding more properties to the nodes (my example might be too far simplified).